# Android: UI Items not visible on certain devices with same resolution

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

I'm in the course of finalising the development of an app and sent it to beta tester with different devices. So far so good and all works perfectly, except for one tester which uses a Sony Experia Z1 with Android 4.4.2. He reports that he cannot see two imageButtons on the screen (see missing buttons on screenshots between the upper value rows and the bottom diallers). All others tester, independently of their devices and resolutions do not report any problems of this sort. It's just that one user. Any help why this happens? I had to cut the xml code below because of the character limitation, the two lower diallers rows are not in there...

Edit: the missing row is the middle piece of the xml in the code below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Calculator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Calculator">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/valueRows"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="50"
            android:baselineAligned="false">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/heatSector"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/heatValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="0.25"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/heatValue"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                        android:text="W/mm2"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ohmSector"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/itemOhmValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="0.57"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/itemOhmValue"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                        android:text="Ohm"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BottomRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TopRow"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:weightSum="50"
            android:baselineAligned="false">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ampSector"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ampValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="15.75"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/ampValue"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                        android:text="Amps"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/wattSector"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/itemWattsValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="150"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/itemWattsValue"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                        android:text="Watts"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/helpButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/help"
            android:onClick="showHelp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/heatSymbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/flame" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ohmSymbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ohm" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/heatSymbol"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/amp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/ohmSymbol"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wattsymbol" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wickRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/valueRows"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cottonElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cottonButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="changeCotton"
            android:src="@drawable/cotton" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/meshElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/meshButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="changeMesh"
            android:src="@drawable/mesh" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parameterRowTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/wickRow"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/coilDiameterElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coilDiameterImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/coildiameter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemCoilDiameterValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coilDiameterImage"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="2.4"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coilDiameterUnit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="mm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/coilDiameterPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coilDiameterImage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/coilDiameterImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="coilDiameterPlusButton"
            android:src="@drawable/plusbutton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/coilDiameterMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coilDiameterImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/coilDiameterImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="coilDiameterMinusButton"
            android:src="@drawable/minusbutton" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wireDiameterElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wireDiameterImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wirediameter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemWireDiameterValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="0.32"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wireDiameterUnit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="mm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wireDiameterPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wireDiameterImage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wireDiameterImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="wireDiameterPlusButton"
            android:src="@drawable/plusbutton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wireDiameterMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wireDiameterImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wireDiameterImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="wireDiameterMinusButton"
            android:src="@drawable/minusbutton" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapsElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wrapsImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wraps" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wrapsValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="6.0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wrapsPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wrapsImage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wrapsImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="wrapsPlusButton"
            android:src="@drawable/plusbutton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wrapsMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wrapsImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wrapsImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="wrapsMinusButton"
            android:src="@drawable/minusbutton" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

.
.
.
.
```

[image: Should Be / Normal Screen]

[image: Faulty Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for all of you which may encounter a similar problem, here my solution to the problem:

I did remove the inner RelativeLayout and just put my two buttons within the outer LinearLayout. Added a weight sum to the latter, and subsequently a weight to each button... works like a charm:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wickRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/valueRows"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >




        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cottonButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="changeCotton"
            android:src="@drawable/cotton"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>




        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/meshButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="changeMesh"
            android:src="@drawable/mesh"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not only the resolution that decides the layout resource but many others can be.

Please read - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You should create screen-specific resources for precise control of your UI.

There are many folders according to screen smallest width and also for different orientations.

For instance -

- ***layout-sw360dp*** - Any orientation with smallest width 360dp
- ***layout-sw360dp-land-xhdpi*** - Only for landscape with smallest width
  360dp and xhdpi devices
- ***layout-sw600dp-land*** - Only for landscape with smallest width 600dp
- ***layout-sw600dp-land-tvdpi*** - Only for landscape with smallest width
  600dp and tvdpi devices
- ***layout-sw720dp-land*** - Only for landscape with smallest width 720dp
- ***layout-sw360dp-port*** - Only for portrait with smallest width 720dp

And many more..

Please check your requirements and place the layout file in appropriate layout folder.

**NOTE:**

The physical density of the `Xperia Z1` is `441 ppi` so it falls into the `xxhdpi` bucket.

For example - `mdpi (160 dpi)` , `hdpi (240 dpi)`, `xhdpi (320 dpi)` and `xxhdpi (480 dpi)`

So we have the formula: *`px = dp * (dpi / 160) or dp = px / (dpi / 160)`*

In this case, *`dpi = 480 and px = 1080`* so:

*`dp = 1080 / (480 / 160) = 1080 / 3 = 360`*

So you should be using -

**layout-sw360dp** for Xperia Z1.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'm not sure though how this should solve my problem, or better said, are you saying I should put an exact copy of my xml into a special folder? and if yes, what should that change?